# Positioning Carosel_slider with Stack, overflows screen pixels

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to move carousel slider a bit left so that it would be in the one line with **Experiences** text.  (I am using **carousel_slider** package)

But when I use Stack in order to position this widget, it is overflowing the screen. I tried putting this slider inside container and giving fixed width and height but nothing changes.

[[image: 1]]

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column( 
     //Row elements
      Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 1,
              child: Container(
                child: carouselSlider = CarouselSlider(
                  height: 390.0,
                  initialPage: 0,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  onPageChanged: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _current = index;
                    });
                  },
                  items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
                    return Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.35,
                            child: Image(
                              image: imgUrl,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

**Error Log**

```
I/flutter (30503): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (30503): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (30503): RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (30503): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter (30503): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter (30503): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderFlex#70b12 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter (30503):   creator: Column ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ←
I/flutter (30503):     LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter (30503):     AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#f921b ink renderer] ← ⋯
I/flutter (30503):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter (30503):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=735.3)
I/flutter (30503):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (30503):   direction: vertical
I/flutter (30503):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter (30503):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter (30503):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter (30503):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter (30503): The constraints that applied to the RenderStack were:
I/flutter (30503):   BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (30503): The exact size it was given was:
I/flutter (30503):   Size(392.7, Infinity)
I/flutter (30503): See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.
I/flutter (30503):
I/flutter (30503): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (30503):   Stack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it somehow with `viewportFraction: 0.9`, so it makes slider bigger and it will stand in the same line with **Experiences** text. 
Also you can set this property to 1.0 in order to make it even bigger